# $|a-i|-|b-j|> c$?

Tags: inequality, absolute-value

Let's have the following inequality:
$$|a-i|-|b-j|> c$$
Where $a,b$ and $c$ are fixed constants and $i,j$  are unknown. I want to determine when does this inequality holds in terms of $i$ and $j$, but I couldn't find how to simplify this any further. Any hints?

EDIT: we have that $|a-b|>c$

EDIT2: $i$ and $j$ are both positive.

Comment: What would be your answer in the special case when $a=b=c=0$? I.e., how would you simplify the inequality $|-i|-|-j|\gt0$?

Comment: @BarryCipra, in this case, it would be $i>j$ ($i$ must be larger than $j$ for this inequality to be true). But I have $|a-b|>c$, I forgot to add it.

Comment: This is gonna be a bit messy... Assume WLOG $a\le b $ and then try distinguishing cases $i,j\lt a $, $i\lt a\le j\lt b $ etc.

Comment: That's not a correct solution.  $(i,j)=(0,-1)$ satisfies $i\gt j$, but $|-0|-|-(-1)|=0-1\not\gt0$.

Comment: If $i$ and $j$ are both be positive or both negative, then we must have $i>j$. If one of them is negative then we must have $i<j$

Comment: With the new condition, how would you simplify the inequality $|i-1|-|j|\gt0$?

Comment: What I'm getting at is that, without some additional context for the problem, it's not clear what it means to "simplify" this inequality.

Comment: @BarryCipra, by "simplify", I mean having inequality (or inequalities for multiple cases) without the absolute values.

Comment: What do we know about a, b and c? Are they positive?

Comment: @user8734617, they are all positive, including $i$ and $j$.

Answer (score 1):

if we have $$a\geq i$$ and $$b\geq j$$ we get $$a-b+j-i>c$$ is this what you want?

Comment: I would like to write this in function of $|a-b|$ which is larger than $c$.